# Dojo mobile Drag & drop

Tags: drag-and-drop, draggable, dojo, web-applications

I need to create a web app that woks with drag and drop,
 in mobile devices, but i can't find documentation in dojo that mentioned that functionality in devices.

if anyone knows  any documentation or examples, would appreciate the help.

this is the library

```
  dojox.mobile
```

am using the version 1.6 of dojo

```
  http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dojox/mobile
```

Comment: I am not sure if 1.6 supports dnd in mobile, however I understand that the up-and-coming 1.7 will have dojo.gestures (or dojo.touch) that will normalize gestures support across browsers.